# Publish a post on a facebook page as page admin

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter, facebook-graph-api

I have CodeIigniter 3 project where I have a blog posts functionality and I would like to add a auto post to Facebook page. I already have configured the HyBridAuth with my CodeIgniter 3 project. Also, I already authenticated my Facebook and stored the data of the Facebook session with access token.

Now, I am trying to post to my facebook page. I have created the following method.

```
public function facebook_post() {
    if ($this->ion_auth->logged_in()) {
        $this->data['userInformation'] = $this->ion_auth->user()->row();
    }
    $this->data['userid'] = $this->data['userInformation']->id;
    $this->data["facebook_status"] = $this->admin_model->getStoredHybridSession($this->data['userid'], "Facebook");

    if(!empty($this->data['facebook_status'][0])) {
        if($this->data["facebook_status"] != "0") {
            $this->data["facebook_profile"] = $this->get_profile("Facebook");
            $access_token = explode('&', $this->data['facebook_profile']->coverInfoURL);
            $a_t = explode('=', $access_token[1]);

            $params = array(
                "access_token" => $a_t[1],
                "message" => "Here is a blog post about auto posting on Facebook using PHP",
                "link" => "http://facebook.com",
                "picture" => "https://i.telegraph.co.uk/multimedia/archive/03474/Facebook_3474124b.jpg",
                "name" => "Auto post functionality test",
                "caption" => "https://facebook.com",
                "description" => "Automatically post on Facebook with PHP using Facebook PHP SDK. How to create a Facebook app. Obtain and extend Facebook access tokens. Cron automation."
            );
            $facebook = $this->hybridauthlib->authenticate("Facebook");
            $ret = $facebook->api()->api('/1388840631445245/feed', 'POST', $params);
            owndebugger('Successfully posted to Facebook');
        }
    } else {
        $this->data["facebook_profile"] = 0;
    }
}
```

This code is working. But, My post posting to page as visitor posts.

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: without checking out your code, you are most likely using a user token instead of a page token.

Comment: @luschn - page token? :( it seems very new terms to me. How do I get that?

Comment: http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens

Comment: read all of that and you will know

Comment: I made already some progress thanks for the suggestions. Can you please tell me which scope is needed to post on page?

Comment: why don´t you start reading the docs? they specifically tell you what scope you need for the api calls. just go to the api reference.

Answer (score 0):

I have completed successfully. :)

To post on page following information are needed to consider.

1) Scope: `publish_pages, publish_actions, manage_pages`

2) You have to store the long lived `access_token` to post regular basis in a page.

3) Then you have to login again with your existing stored session in your post method as follows:

```
$this->data["facebook_profile"] = $this->get_user_pages("Facebook");
    $params = array(
    "access_token" => $this->data['facebook_profile'][0]['access_token'],
    "message" => $this->input->post('posttitle'),
    "link" => base_url() . "news/" . $this->results,
    "picture" => base_url() . "uploads/posts/".(isset($profilephoto['file_name']) ? $profilephoto['file_name'] : $pp),
    "name" => "Stack Overflow",
     "caption" => "http://stackoverflow.com",
     "description" => $this->input->post('postcontent')
    );
// post on a single page of my pages
    $facebook = $this->hybridauthlib->authenticate("Facebook");
    $facebook->api()->api("/221320344636/feed", 'POST', $params );
```

4) `$this->get_user_pages("Facebook")`. Here `get_user_pages` retrieving your all pages `access_token` and then you can select `access_token` one of your pages to post on that page.

And I would like to give a special thanks to @luschn for his help. :)